# Custom player for YouTube video

Tags: reactjs, video, youtube, video-player

I want to implement video player in my React project. Best decision use YouTube video on my site, but hide YouTube "More" dots, buttons share and so on. So this is the way user could not go to youtube page or share the video. Only one option to watch the video must be in my web page. Is it possible? Or decision is to create/install custom player and src YouTube video? Or maybe another advices, what is the best way to show the video in the site?
So first photo its what I've got now, second its wat I want to have:

[image: exemple]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the react-player library. It is a third party library but I think this would suffice. Remember to install the library through npm first!

> npm install react-player

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

const VideoPlayer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="video-wrapper">
      <ReactPlayer
        url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID"
        controls={false} // Hide controls
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried this, but I want to hide "More" dots, buttons share and so on. So this is the way user could not go to youtube page or share the video. Only one option to watch the video must be in my web page. Is it possible?